# Only two of three Kingston SSDs are detected in official Kingston SSD Manager tool

Tags: ssd, storage

So I have the following three SSDs

- SA400S37/480G
- SA400S37/120G
- SUV400S37/120G

First of two are detected and visible in Kingston SSD Manger tool but the last one is not?

What does it mean? Can it be not an original Kingston drive but a Chinese copy instead?

[image]

P.S. SA400S37/120G is not used now in my PC (but it was in the list as well, just like SA400S37/480G)

Windows Device Manager:

[image]

AIDA64:

[image]

**Updated**

a screenshot from **events** tab:

[image]

Comment: Seems like the “SA400S37/120G” is not even being recognized at all in Windows. Are you sure it works? What if you connect it to another SATA connector?

Comment: Are all drives connected similarly? If yes and it's new, ask for a replacement. If old, it might be dead.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I mentioned it. Yes, it works, but now it's disconnected

Comment: @harrymc the SSD itself works, the Windows is running on it right now

Answer (score 0):

You say that an SSD that is not shown in the Kingston SSD Manager,
is working correctly and showing up in Disk Management.

In this case this is a problem with the Kingston SSD Manager.

Install the latest version of the
[Kingston SSD Manager](https://www.kingston.com/en/support/technical/ssdmanager).
If the problem still exists with this version, you should
signal the bug to Kingston Support.

Comment: It's the latest version, yeah

Comment: yeah, I guess I need contact the manufacture